# Paypal subscription immediate payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I am currently working on integrating PayPal subscriptions into our platform and have encountered a scenario where I need to implement immediate payments using a subscription ID or modify the next billing cycle due date. Could you please provide guidance or point me to the appropriate resources or APIs to achieve this?

Specifically, I'm looking for information on how to:

Capture an immediate payment using a subscription ID.
Change the next billing cycle due date for a subscription.
Any code samples or best practices would be greatly appreciated to ensure a smooth integration.